# render JSON tree object in html table

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an problem in rendering a tree structure json in to the html so that i can have a view like in the image attached.

[image]

```js
list for repeat in the table

   list = [
  {
    "level": "1",
    "leafFlag": "1",
    "path": "r125",
    "name": "car",
    "children": [
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "1",
        "path": "r125/yhes",
        "name": "tata"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "level": "1",
    "leafFlag": "1",
    "path": "p123",
    "name": "food",
    "children": [
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "1",
        "path": "p123/p095",
        "name": "banana",
        "children": [
          {
            "level": "3",
            "leafFlag": "0",
            "path": "p123/p095/p546",
            "name": "grapes"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "level": "2",
        "leafFlag": "0",
        "path": "p123/p345",
        "name": "apple"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```html
I tried something like this but didnt work

<tbody *ngFor="let element of list">
                    <tr *ngIf="element && (!element.children || element.children.length === 0); else loggedOut">
                        <td>
                            {{element.level}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ element.path }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <ng-template #loggedOut>
                        <tr *ngFor="let child of element.children">
                            <td>
                                {{child.level}}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ child.path }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                </tbody>
```

I tried with below syntax but am not able to do that

but its not printing correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6bhq3)

I changed your logout tbody to

```
<tbody *ngFor="let element of newarr">
<tr *ngIf="element && (!element.children || element.children.length === 0); else loggedOut">
    <td  [style.paddingLeft]="element.level*10+'px'">{{element.level}}</td>
    <td>{{ element.path }} </td>
</tr>
```

in component convert from your nested object array to single object array

```
  newarr=[];
  ngOnInit(){ 
    this.arr.forEach(element=>{ 
      this.newarr.push({level:element.level,path:element.path}) 
      if(element.children&&element.children.length>0){
          this.callback(element.children); 
      } 
    }) 
  }
  callback(element){
    element.forEach(x=>{
      this.newarr.push({level:x.level,path:x.path})
       if(x.children&&x.children.length>0){ this.callback(x.children);  }
    })
  }
```

Comment: it works for level 1 and level 2 but i have n levels

Comment: Updated answer @AkRoy

Comment: but where is the loggedOut template?

Comment: You don't need it if you convert to single object array

Comment: U can check demo link